# Tikz-UML sequence diagram: how to extend lifeline and shrink vertical space before \umlfpart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I am using [Tikz UML](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc#t-4) to create a sequence diagram.

How can I extend the lifeline of `c:C` and `d:D` to match the lifeline length of `b:B`?
And how can I shrink the vertical space before the dashed line produced by `\umlfpart`?

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzumlset{fill object = white, fill call = gray!20} 
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=B]{b}
\umlobject[class=C]{c}
\umlobject[class=D]{d}


\begin{umlfragment}[type=loop]
\begin{umlcallself}[op=run]{b} 

\begin{umlcall}[op=send, type=asynchron]{b}{c}
    \begin{umlfragment}[type=alt, label=condition, inner xsep=8]
        \begin{umlcall}[op=send, type=synchron, return=send update]{c}{d}
            \begin{umlcallself}[padding=1.5, op=run]{d} 
            \end{umlcallself}
        \end{umlcall}
        \begin{umlcallself}[op=assess update]{c} 
            \begin{umlcall}[op=send update, type=synchron, return=acknowledge]{c}{b}
            \end{umlcall}
            \begin{umlcall}[op=allow continue, type=asynchron]{c}{b}
            \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlcallself}
        \umlfpart[default]
        \begin{umlcall}[op=allow continue, type=asynchron]{c}{b}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlfragment}
\end{umlcall}

\end{umlcallself}

\end{umlfragment}

\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what I currently have:

[image: sequence diagram]

I'd like to have the extended lifelines like this:

[image]

Comment: For the second question: `\begin{umlcall}[op=allow continue, type=asynchron,padding=-2.5]{c}{b}`. I would link the author to this as the extra space is hard coded in order to fit the `return` above. I think that is an erro. On the other part. Why would you want to do that? It is semantically wrong, I believe. Are you sure that you need a sequence diagram for your purpose?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Is the author of `tikz-uml` on tex.stackexchange.com? Regarding the lifeline: I added another image of my desired result. Why would that be semantically wrong? `c` and `d` continue to exist but are not active. What kind of schematic visualization would you recommend instead?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thanks I will contact him about the padding

Comment: Maybe you do a feature request for those enlarged lines. [pgf-umlsd](http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2011/11/24/creating-uml-sequence-diagrams-with-tikz-in-latex/) does this by default.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I tried pgf-umlsd but it has no support for the horizontal dashed line within the alt block. Do you know how that would work?

Comment: As author of tikz-uml, I will react to the first question: according to UML definitions, like [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_sequencediagram.html) for instance, an ending lifeline does not mean that the object is destroyed but that it is the end of its activity in the sequence diagram. But fragments definition does not intervene for lifelines, so there will be a way to define where a lifeline ends in the new release of tikz-uml available soon.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of `tikz-uml` mentioned by [N. Kielbasiewicz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/100441/n-kielbasiewicz) (`tikz-uml` author) in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252933/tikz-uml-sequence-diagram-how-to-extend-lifeline-and-shrink-vertical-space-befo#comment723684_252933) has been released it seems. As mentioned in the manual, the `\umlsdnode` macro is now available for extending lifelines, so for your example you can try for example

```
\umlsdnode[dt=1.5]{b}
\umlsdnode[dt=5]{c}
\umlsdnode[dt=32]{d}
```

I also added [LaRiFaRi's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252933/tikz-uml-sequence-diagram-how-to-extend-lifeline-and-shrink-vertical-space-befo#comment603821_252933) of negative `padding` to reduce the vertical spacing.

Complete code:

[image: partial output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzumlset{fill object = white, fill call = gray!20} 
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=B]{b}
\umlobject[class=C]{c}
\umlobject[class=D]{d}


\begin{umlfragment}[type=loop]
\begin{umlcallself}[op=run]{b} 

\begin{umlcall}[op=send, type=asynchron]{b}{c}
    \begin{umlfragment}[type=alt, label=condition, inner xsep=8]
        \begin{umlcall}[op=send, type=synchron, return=send update]{c}{d}
            \begin{umlcallself}[padding=1.5, op=run]{d} 
            \end{umlcallself}
        \end{umlcall}
        \begin{umlcallself}[op=assess update]{c} 
            \begin{umlcall}[op=send update, type=synchron, return=acknowledge]{c}{b}
            \end{umlcall}
            \begin{umlcall}[op=allow continue, padding=-2.5, type=asynchron]{c}{b}
            \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlcallself}
        \umlfpart[default]
        \begin{umlcall}[op=allow continue, type=asynchron]{c}{b}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlfragment}
\end{umlcall}

\end{umlcallself}

\end{umlfragment}
\umlsdnode[dt=1.5]{b}
\umlsdnode[dt=5]{c}
\umlsdnode[dt=32]{d}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```