# How to draw dashed horizontal line in sequence diagram using pgf-umlsd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

I am drawing a sequence diagram using Tikz. I first tried `tikz-uml`, but it has some issues which I asked about in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252933/tikz-uml-sequence-diagram-how-to-extend-lifeline-and-shrink-vertical-space-befo).

I am now trying out `pgf-umlsd`, but it lacks the support for the dashed horizontal line which separates the alternatives in the `alt` block.

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
  \newthread{t}{:Thread}
  \newinst[1]{i}{:Instance}

  \begin{sdblock}{alt}{[condition]}
    \begin{call}{t}{if\_true()}{i}{}
    \end{call}
 \begin{call}{t}{if\_false()}{i}{}
    \end{call}
  \end{sdblock}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image: original]

I'd like to draw a dashed line between the two alternatives like this.
How can I do that?

[image: desired output]

I already found [a definition of \separateline](https://github.com/lyarbean/Tex-stuff/blob/master/pgf-umlsd-ex.tex), however the line is not starting/ending at the border of the `alt` block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\separateline}[3][dotted, color=black, very thick]{
    \stepcounter{seqlevel}
    \path
    (#2)+(.1,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-.8*\unitfactor) node (from) {}
    (#3)+(-.1,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-.8*\unitfactor) node (to) {};
    \draw[#1] (from) -- (to);
}

\begin{sequencediagram}
  \newthread{t}{:Thread}
  \newinst[1]{i}{:Instance}

  \begin{sdblock}{alt}{[condition]}
    \begin{call}{t}{if\_true()}{i}{}
    \end{call}

\separateline{t}{i}

 \begin{call}{t}{if\_false()}{i}{}
    \end{call}
  \end{sdblock}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into `pgf-umlsd.sty` file, will see that the `sdblock` is drawn as a `rectangle` with corners on coordinates `nw` and `se`. And these coordinates will be redefined with every new `sdblock`.

Then my suggestion consists in drawing separation line right after every `sdblock`. And in case, you want some separation between inside block elements use `\stepcounter`.

The complete code could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd} % Already loads TiKZ and libraries arrows and shadows

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
  \newthread{t}{:Thread}
  \newinst[1]{i}{:Instance}

  \begin{sdblock}{alt}{[condition]}
    \begin{call}{t}{if\_true()}{i}{}
    \end{call}

    \stepcounter{seqlevel} %Vertical empty space between `calls`

    \begin{call}{t}{if\_false()}{i}{}
    \end{call}
  \end{sdblock}

  \path (nw)--coordinate (aux) (se); 
  \draw[dashed] (nw|-aux)--(aux-|se);
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: any clever way to draw it in the place of the separator instead of the middle of block?

Comment: @majkrzak Sorry but I don't understand your question. May be you want to make a public question with reference to this one. This way you'll get more readers and probably better help.